# Nested while loop in PHP is not working for MySQL database queries

Tags: php, dynamic, menu, while-loop, nested

All the whole day I'm trying to solve this problem but still no luck.

The scenario is: I am developing a vertical menu which should query groups and items of those groups in a menu respectively, but groups are being populated without its items.

Code was written in the following way:

```
$data1 = mysql_query(select groupnames from groups where categoryy='Agriculture');

while($info1=mysql_fetch_array($data1))
{

    echo $info1[0];
    $data2==mysql_query(select itms from groupitems where categoryy='Agriculture' and    groupname='$info1[0]');
    while($info2=mysql_fetch_array($data2))
    {
    echo $info2[0];
    }
}
```

In the above code, groups are being populated nicely but no items from groupitems table are being populated. If I write `Grain` (`Grain` is one of the group of agriculture in my database) instead of `groupname=$info1[0]` then it works. But it should be got dynamically from the query.

Please help, I'm in trouble.

at last its solved! here's the code:

```
<?php
include "aPannel/dbconn.php";
$query="select GroupName from categorygroup where categoryy='Agriculture'";

$i=0; 

$result=mysql_query($query);
$num=mysql_num_rows($result);
$groupname=mysql_result($result ,$i ,"GroupName"); 
mysql_close();

if ($num=="0") echo "<p>Sorry, there are no groups to display for this Category.</p>"; 

else 
{ 
echo "<p>There are currently <strong>$num</strong> groups represented in our database.</p><br>"; 

while($i < $num) 
{
    $groupname=mysql_result($result ,$i ,"GroupName"); 
    include("aPannel/dbconn.php");
    $query2 = "SELECT subcategory FROM groupsubcategory WHERE groupname='$groupname'"; // count number of items in each group 
    echo $query2 . "<br/>"; 
    $resultt=mysql_query($query2);
    $countt=mysql_num_rows($resultt); 
    mysql_close();
    echo $countt . "subcategories" . "<br/>"; // display number of items 
     $i++; 
    } 
} // end if results 
?>
```

Comment: Make sure you posted correct code

Comment: $data2==mysql_query("select itms from groupitems where categoryy='Agriculture' and    groupname='".$info1[0]."'"); this code has this error " is missing

Comment: write `error_reporting(E_ALL);` at top of script, then you will get errors.

Answer (score 0):

Your queries are not wrapped around `double-quotes (" ")` . Always remember that what you pass to `mysql_query` method is a string argument. And also `$data2==....` seems wrong.

So, change the code like this

```
     $data1=mysql_query("select groupnames from groups where categoryy='Agriculture'");

    while($info1=mysql_fetch_array($data1))
    {

        echo $info1[0];
        $infoTemp=$info1[0];
        $data2=mysql_query("select itms from groupitems where categoryy='Agriculture' 
and    groupname='$infoTemp'");
        while($info2=mysql_fetch_array($data2))
        {
        echo $info2[0];
        }
    }
```

I hope it should work

**EDIT:** Also are you sure column `itms` in second query or `items` ? 
**EDIT:**  added temporary variable

Comment: $data1=mysql_query("select groupnames from groups where categoryy='Agriculture'");

while($info1=mysql_fetch_array($data1))
{

    echo $info1[0];
    $data2==mysql_query("select itms from groupitems where categoryy='Agriculture' and    groupname='$info1[0]'");
    while($info2=mysql_fetch_array($data2))
    {
    echo $info2[0];
    }
}

Comment: @TOHFATULISLAMMILTON so, what do you mean by this comment...did my answer work or not?

Comment: yah, i used " . the problem is, probably $info1[0] is an array and it can not be used as a parameter value for the where condition. if I want to print or echo i.e echo $info1[0] then it works but what should be if i want to use it in a select statement?

Comment: @TOHFATULISLAMMILTON simple, assign `$info1[0]` to a temporary variable `$temp=$info1[0]` and use `$temp` in the query. ok? see my updated answer

Comment: @TOHFATULISLAMMILTON your question is not clear...what's the error you get?

Comment: there's no error. i was just trying to populate group names and items of that group from my table using the nested loop. but the php script is giving me only the group names of agriculture category without any items from the group. it seems like the problem is very simple but still i've no solution.

Comment: @TOHFATULISLAMMILTON did you see you were using == symbol instead of = while assigning to $data2==mysql_.............

Comment: i noticed that. only problem is the $info1[0] is aa array and if i assign it to any variable that also becomes an array. not sure what is the solution

Comment: @TOHFATULISLAMMILTON if $info1 is an array $info1[0] is not an array of the same type...indeed $info1[0] is a string (string that can be indexed indeed)

Comment: @TOHFATULISLAMMILTON so how did I help you in any way?

Comment: yah, there were something to learn from u but main solution came from after googling. thanks.